# Storing ad tag in JS variable

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to store a JS ad tag/javascript/html in a JS variable to later be recalled and run on the page. Currently I am unable to do so as the '"/script"' in the tag is breaking the code and preventing things from running. I cannot modify the code being saved in to the variable. Is this even possible?

Basically I want to store a chunk of code and then run it when needed.

Thanks for your help.

Example ad tag:

```
<script src="https://exampleurl.com.bs?cn=rsb&c=28&pli=222425437261&PluID=0&w=300&h=250&ncu=$$%%CLICK_URL_UNESC%%$$&ord=%%CACHEBUSTER%%&ucm=true"></script>
<noscript>
<a href="%%CLICK_URL_UNESC%%https://exampleurl.com.bs?cn=brd&FlightID=25242437261&Page=&PluID=0&Pos=185504870" target="_blank"><img src="https://exampleurl.com.bs?cn=bsr&FlightID=25242437261&Page=&PluID=0&Pos=185504870" border=0 width=300 height=250></a>
</noscript>
```

Comment: post some code or we cant help you :)

Comment: A javascript variable is short live. You'll need to store such information in cookies.

Comment: Added example code to be stored. Thanks !

Answer (score 0):

There are three methods that I can think of at the top of my head:

---

**1. Separate file for JavaScript operations** (I'd recommend this)

This is pretty much self-explanatory:

`index.html`

```
<script src="myFile.js"></script>
```

`myFile.js`

```
var ad = [insertAdAsAStringHere];
```

Then you can reference your HTML as a string with the `ad` variable.

---

**2. Manually escape the tag** (Kinda weird at first, but works)

You can replace `</script>` with something like `</script&gt` or `&lt/script>`, which will prevent HTML rendering it as a tag when your page loads, but will still render as normal HTML when you render it through JavaScript.

---

**3. ConCat.** (meow!)

Split your string! If you split it in between the script tag, for example:

```
var myTag = "<script>console.log('hi')<" + "/script>";
car myOtherTag = "<script>console.log('hi')</scri" + "pt>";
```

This will split the characters apart, while still maintaining the desired result.

---

Hope this helped!